# How to turn on text to speech engine in Twilio?

Tags: twilio, text-to-speech

I would like to not only record calls but turn on text to speech. Twilio samples are pretty vague how to use `<Record>` verb(inside, next or outside the `<Dial>` verb) so I turned the recordings by:

```
<Response>
<Dial record="true" callerId="48326304351">
<Client>jenny</Client>
</Dial>
</Response>
```

The call is successfuly recorded, but I would like to turn on text to speech engine.

When I did this:

```
<Response>
<Dial callerId="48326304351">
<Client>jenny</Client>
</Dial>
<Record timeout="20" transcribe="true"/>
</Response>
```

The recording is not present also I have no idea where transcription of the audio is.

I tried also this, altough I don't even know where the transcribtion would be:

```
<Response>
<Dial record="true" transcribe="true" callerId="48326304351">
<Client>jenny</Client>
</Dial>
</Response>
```

Answer (score 0):

Twilio developer evangelist here.

The transcription (speech to text) service is currently only available on the [`<Record>`](https://www.twilio.com/docs/api/twiml/record#attributes-transcribe) verb in TwiML. Notably it can only be used to transcribe messages 2 minutes or less in length as well.

There is no option to transcribe two (or more) legged calls.

Comment: Thank you for info but as I stated I probably use Record verb in wrong manner, as I don't know how it should relate to the Dial verb.

Comment: Right, you are using the Record verb wrong as it cannot be nested or have other verbs nested in it. The record verb is for recording a message from a single participant in a call. Transcription can only be performed on a recording from one person only.